# Python: Patch the print function for a particular function call? (Decorator for printing the recursion tree)

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, monkeypatching

I wrote a decorator for printing the recursion tree produced by some function call.

```
from functools import wraps

def printRecursionTree(func):
    global _recursiondepth
    _print = print
    _recursiondepth = 0

    def getpads():
        if _recursiondepth == 0:
            strFn    = '{} └──'.format(' │  ' * (_recursiondepth-1))
            strOther = '{}  ▒▒'.format(' │  ' * (_recursiondepth-1))
            strRet   = '{}    '.format(' │  ' * (_recursiondepth-1))
        else:
            strFn    = '    {} ├──'.format(' │  ' * (_recursiondepth-1))
            strOther = '    {} │▒▒'.format(' │  ' * (_recursiondepth-1))
            strRet   = '    {} │  '.format(' │  ' * (_recursiondepth-1))

        return strFn, strRet, strOther

    def indentedprint():
        @wraps(print)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            strFn, strRet, strOther = getpads()
            _print(strOther, end=' ')
            _print(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper


    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global _recursiondepth
        global print

        strFn, strRet, strOther = getpads()

        if args and kwargs:
            _print(strFn, '{}({}, {}):'.format(func.__qualname__, ', '.join(args), kwargs))
        else:
            _print(strFn, '{}({}):'.format(func.__qualname__, ', '.join(map(str, args)) if args else '', kwargs if kwargs else ''))
        _recursiondepth += 1
        print, backup = indentedprint(), print
        retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print = backup
        _recursiondepth -= 1
        _print(strRet, '╰', retval)
        if _recursiondepth == 0:
            _print()
        return retval

    return wrapper
```

Example usage:

```
@printRecursionTree
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        print('Base Case')
        return n
    print('Recursive Case')
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

# This works with mutually recursive functions too,
# since the variable _recursiondepth is global
@printRecursionTree
def iseven(n):
    print('checking if even')
    if n == 0: return True
    return isodd(n-1)

@printRecursionTree
def isodd(n):
    print('checking if odd')
    if n == 0: return False
    return iseven(n-1)

iseven(5)
fib(5)

'''Prints:

└── iseven(5):
     │▒▒ checking if even
     │▒▒ Note how the print
     │▒▒ statements get nicely indented
     ├── isodd(4):
     │   │▒▒ checking if odd
     │   ├── iseven(3):
     │   │   │▒▒ checking if even
     │   │   │▒▒ Note how the print
     │   │   │▒▒ statements get nicely indented
     │   │   ├── isodd(2):
     │   │   │   │▒▒ checking if odd
     │   │   │   ├── iseven(1):
     │   │   │   │   │▒▒ checking if even
     │   │   │   │   │▒▒ Note how the print
     │   │   │   │   │▒▒ statements get nicely indented
     │   │   │   │   ├── isodd(0):
     │   │   │   │   │   │▒▒ checking if odd
     │   │   │   │   │   ╰ False
     │   │   │   │   ╰ False
     │   │   │   ╰ False
     │   │   ╰ False
     │   ╰ False
     ╰ False

 └── fib(5):
     │▒▒ Recursive Case
     ├── fib(4):
     │   │▒▒ Recursive Case
     │   ├── fib(3):
     │   │   │▒▒ Recursive Case
     │   │   ├── fib(2):
     │   │   │   │▒▒ Recursive Case
     │   │   │   ├── fib(1):
     │   │   │   │   │▒▒ Base Case
     │   │   │   │   ╰ 1
     │   │   │   ├── fib(0):
     │   │   │   │   │▒▒ Base Case
     │   │   │   │   ╰ 0
     │   │   │   ╰ 1
     │   │   ├── fib(1):
     │   │   │   │▒▒ Base Case
     │   │   │   ╰ 1
     │   │   ╰ 2
     │   ├── fib(2):
     │   │   │▒▒ Recursive Case
     │   │   ├── fib(1):
     │   │   │   │▒▒ Base Case
     │   │   │   ╰ 1
     │   │   ├── fib(0):
     │   │   │   │▒▒ Base Case
     │   │   │   ╰ 0
     │   │   ╰ 1
     │   ╰ 3
     ├── fib(3):
     │   │▒▒ Recursive Case
     │   ├── fib(2):
     │   │   │▒▒ Recursive Case
     │   │   ├── fib(1):
     │   │   │   │▒▒ Base Case
     │   │   │   ╰ 1
     │   │   ├── fib(0):
     │   │   │   │▒▒ Base Case
     │   │   │   ╰ 0
     │   │   ╰ 1
     │   ├── fib(1):
     │   │   │▒▒ Base Case
     │   │   ╰ 1
     │   ╰ 2
     ╰ 5
'''
```

This example code works correctly **as long as it is in the same file where the decorator is defined**.

If however one imports the decorator from some module, the print statements no longer get indented.

I understand that this behaviour arises because the print statement patched by the decorator is a global for it's own module, is not shared across modules.

1. How do I fix this?
2. Is there a better way of patching a function only for a particular call to another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the behavior of the builtin print function for all modules by replacing it in the `builtins` module.

So change your assignments to global variable `print` with assignments to `builtins.print` (after importing `builtins`):

```
import builtins

...

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global _recursiondepth # no more need for global print up here

        strFn, strRet, strOther = getpads()

        if args and kwargs:
            _print(strFn, '{}({}, {}):'.format(func.__qualname__, ', '.join(args), kwargs))
        else:
            _print(strFn, '{}({}):'.format(func.__qualname__, ', '.join(map(str, args)) if args else '', kwargs if kwargs else ''))
        _recursiondepth += 1
        builtins.print, backup = indentedprint(), print   # change here
        retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
        builtins.print = backup                           # and here
        _recursiondepth -= 1
        _print(strRet, '╰', retval)
        if _recursiondepth == 0:
            _print()
        return retval
```

Comment: Quick and short! Thanks. Is patching builtins like this considered dangerous?

Comment: I don't think it's too dangerous as long as you keep a reference to the original version of `print`, but to do it safely you probably need some extra logic in your code for handling exceptions. For instance, I'd suggest putting a `try` statement before the call to `func` (which would need to be indented one more level), and put the `builtins.print = backup` line in a `finally` clause. You might want the `_recursiondepth` updates to be handled that way too.